# php logic loop step by 5

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading an excell file with php. No problem with that but I am stuck on a little logical part. I want to make an array that containts multiple other arrays with data.

The data is provided in my excell file I know from what column should start reading but not when to stop because this is dynamic.

My question is how can a make a loop that reads my columns and makes on every 5th column a new array.

so what I want is something like this:

```
(My data for the excell file is proved in $line[] each column has its number.)
        array(
        'length' => $line[15],
        'width' => $line[16]
        'price_per' => $line[17],
        'price' => $line[18],
        'stock' => $line[19]
    ),
    array(
        'length' => $line[20],
        'width' => $line[21]
        'price_per' => $line[22],
        'price' => $line[23],
        'stock' => $line[24]
    ),
    array(
        'length' => $line[25],
        'width' => $line[26]
        'price_per' => $line[27],
        'price' => $line[28],
        'stock' => $line[29]
    ), ....
```

So how can I make this dynamic (for loop ?) so that I have 1 big indexed Array , with multiple asscociated arrays? Note: my for loop should always star from line[15]!

Answer (score 7):

To begin with, if `$line` has any elements that you don't want to process (e.g. the first 15 as your example indicates), slice them off with [`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$line = array_slice($line, 15);
```

Then use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split your original array into as many pieces as there are:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($line, 5);
```

Then, turn each chunk into its own array by associating each value with the correct key using [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$results = array();
$keys = array('length', 'width', 'price_per', 'price', 'stock');
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    $results[] = array_combine($keys, $chunk);
}
```

Comment: I like it, he'd have to delete the three first arrays though (in his particular case)

Comment: +1 Damn, exactly how I rewrote my answer; don't forget to slice the array from index 15 first :)

Comment: @Jack: I owe you one upvote that I couldn't give here, plus one for being disciplined ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i = 15; $i < ????; $i += 5)
{
    $your_array[] = array(
        'length' => $line[$i],
        'width' => $line[$i+1]
        'price_per' => $line[$i+2],
        'price' => $line[$i+3],
        'stock' => $line[$i+4]
    );
}
```

Replace ???? by the number of lines

Comment: excelent very simple !